# ASP.net Session state cookie issue

Tags: asp.net

I have a curious problem. I have an older aspx web forms site that uses the ASP_Session state cookie for session management. I have a page that loads fine and the code behind adds a number of things to the session and the page renders. The session cookie however doesn't get sent to the browser, so when the user clicks on a next button they get redirected to the standard error page as they aren't sending any cookie with the request and the next button takes them to step two of a form.

The error page sends a session cookie, so if the user reloads the initial page, and the clicks the next button it now works.

It's weird to me that virtually every page on the site will send a session cookies but this one. Any ideas?

Comment: *the code behind adds a number of things to the session and the page renders* Instead of describing your code to us, could you show us the actual code? Obviously there is something wrong in there but there's no way to troubleshoot it from your description. Also, please see [ask].

Comment: Is everything happening in SSL meaning you are not jumping between http and https?